# How to install JDBC driver for java version 10

Tags: java, jdbc, driver

I have been using java version 8 for these days.

Now I installed java version 10, but I can't find a  `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` for Java version 10.

In Java version 8 I know the JDBC connector jar file is copied into the ext folder inside java `JDK/jre/lib` but in java version 10 there no ext folder inside it.

So I need to know how to install JDBC driver in java version 10.

Comment: you should not mess with ext folder. set correct CLASSPATH. driver for java 8 should work fine.

Comment: java 8 works fine but I installed Java 10. so I need to find how to install JDBC driver for Java version 10.

Comment: What he meant is that Java 8 driver should work fine *for Java 10*. Do not include libraries in the JDK but set correct CLASSPATH in your compilation.

Comment: You shouldn't have been using the `ext` folder in Java 8 either. That is not the correct way to add dependencies to your application (and it has never been the correct way).

Comment: can I know how to set the classpath?

Comment: What are you using to compile? An IDE? Which one?

Comment: I'm using NetBeans on that I have a JDBC connector. I need this for compiling programs using cmd.